# Overlapping histograms in SPSS with multiple variables

Tags: spss

I have three index variables and I want to show how the variables differ in their distribution. Is it posible to make a single figure in SPSS, containing overlapping histograms for three different variables?

I want something like this:

[image: Overlapping histograms]

Note, I do not want to create an overlapping histogram based on a single quantitative variable and a categorical variable, but on three different quantitative variables.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know how to run a histogram on one quantitative variable + a categorical variable, you can simply restructure:

```
varstocases /make val from x y z/index=var(val).
```

Now you can use `val` as your single quantitative variable, and `var` (which contains the original variable name) as your categorical variable.

If you want to do the above without losing your present data structure, you can do this:

```
dataset name PresentStructure.
dataset copy ForAnalysis.
dataset activate ForAnalysis.
varstocases /make val from x y z/index=var(val).
.... Run your analyses here ......
dataset activate PresentStructure.
dataset close ForAnalysis.
```